# Topological embedding of graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I was reading the following proof of the claim that every graph can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

https://sometimesfun.wordpress.com/2015/08/02/embedding-graphs-in-r3/

At the end, there is the following note:

"Although I called this construction an ’embedding’, for lack of a better term, it, the ’embedding’ isn’t a topological embedding of the graph, i.e. the image isn’t homeomorphic to the CW-complex representing the graph."

I don't understand what this means (probably because I know nothing about CW-complexes). I know that an embedding of a graph is basically a drawing, but can someone please explain to me, at least on an intuitive level, what is the difference between an embedding of a graph as is constructed in the above proof, and a topological embedding of a graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The author must be referring to the "general construction"? Because I agree with you that the finite construction certainly seems to give a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ homeomorphic to the graph.

Comment: @user7530 I think you are probably right. But I still don't understand the difference between a topological embedding and an embedding as described in the proof. I mean, what is the problem in the infinite case that causes the "shape" of the original graph to sort of change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, consider a graph with infinite valence at one vertex, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2.$ There must be a sequence of edges with slopes converging to some value. (The same will be true if the graph is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it's easier to visualize in the plane.) Thus you have a subgraph which isn't closed, so this is not a topological embedding, if you endow your graph with the CW topology, which should be thought of as the topology coming only from the cells.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies the situation a bit. I am still having some trouble though because I am completely unfamiliar with the concept of infinite graphs. In any case you have been very helpful, thanks again!

Comment: @Ilefen A graph is just a set of vertices and a set of edges. Either set can be infinite, and the valence of any vertex can be infinite. The CW topology doesn't allow us to consider any vertex or edge to be "near" another vertex or edge, except if they are attached, of course. But as subsets of Euclidean space, we may not be able to fit all the edges in without some "bunching up". As an even simpler example, consider that we cannot embed an infinite discrete graph (no edges at all) within the unit interval without some of them "bunching up". Of course, for finite graphs, there are no issues.

Comment: Brilliant,  I think I've completely got it. Thanks a million!

Comment: One more question. Does this mean that an infinite graph cannot be embedded (in the topological sense) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in any way? What I mean is, in the proof I posted there was a construction of an "embedding" of G. Was the problem the construction itself, or the fact that the graph is infinite?

Comment: @Ilefen I can think of infinite graphs that embed in $\mathbb{R}$ without problems. For example, the discrete lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3.$  Or the connected coordinate lattice with edges. I can see two ways that an infinite graph can fail to have a topological embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3:$ if any vertex has an infinite valence, or if the vertex set is uncountably infinite. Is this a necessary condition? Do there exist graphs with countable vertex sets an finite valence that still cannot be embedded? My guess is "no", but I'm not sure. Might be a good topic for new question.

Comment: as for the proof in the link you posted, it is a valid proof showing that all graphs can be embedded _as incidence structures_. It says nothing at all about topological embeddings. For what it shows, there's nothing wrong with it. It does seem that that proof is sensitive to cardinality though, right? certainly it seems clear that if for example your vertex set has cardinality greater than c, there's no way to embed in any $\mathbb{R}^n$, not even as an incidence structure, let alone a topological space.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding as well. A further problem is that if you don't accept the continuum hypothesis there is no way you can complete the proof. In any case I thought it was very elegant.